# playframework java async method call

Tags: java, email, asynchronous, playframework

playframework 2.2 (java 7)

I have REST api where receive some json, with json data I'm doing some stuff and on the end I'm sending email and return Results. Sending email is kind of slow, so 
I want after handling json call this email method in other thread or I want to execute asynchronous and return results without waiting execution of email method.

How to implement and call async method in controller ?

Here is example of code

```
 public static Result register() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null)
        Logger.info("bad json request");
    try {
        RegistrationHandler registrationHandler = new RegistrationHandler();
        if(!registrationHandler.isEmailUnique(json)){
            return ok("false");
        }else{
            registrationHandler.saveUser(json);
            String email = json.findValue("email").asText();
            sendRegistrationEmail(email); // I don't want wait this for execution
            return ok("success");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ok("error");
}
```

Edit:

Not sure if it's good, but works.

```
 JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null)
        Logger.info("bad json request");
    try {
        RegistrationHandler registrationHandler = new RegistrationHandler();
        if(!registrationHandler.isEmailUnique(json)){
            return ok("false");
        }else{
            registrationHandler.saveUser(json);
            String email = json.findValue("email").asText();
            F.Promise<java.lang.Boolean> emailPromise = F.Promise.promise(
              new F.Function0<java.lang.Boolean>() {
                public java.lang.Boolean apply() {
                    return sendRegistrationEmail(email);
                }
              }
            );

            return ok("success");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ok("error");
```

Comment: In your code after 'edit' you return ok("success") before the actual sending of the email happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and the example in
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync#Async-results
But I never actually run this code (nor compiled).

The point is that you have to return a Promise. Play handles the rest. You could just return with ok() after the first Promise that calls `sendRegistrationEmail(email)` but then you'd loose the ability to send an "error" in case something during the sending goes wrong.

```
public static Promise<Result> myMethod() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null) {
        Logger.info("bad json request");
        return badRequest();
    }

    RegistrationHandler registrationHandler = new RegistrationHandler();
    if(!registrationHandler.isEmailUnique(json)) {
        return ok("false");
    }

    registrationHandler.saveUser(json);
    String email = json.findValue("email").asText();
    F.Promise<Boolean> emailPromise = F.Promise.promise(
        new F.Function0<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply() {
            // This method takes a while
            return sendRegistrationEmail(email);
        }
    });

    return emailPromise.map(new Function<Boolean, Result>() {
        public Result apply(Boolean successful) {
            if (successful) {
                return ok("success");
            } else {
                return ok("error");
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Promise to handle the JSON retrieval and processing, you can attach a callback for when the Promise is redeemed.

This code is based on the example from [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync).

```
public static Promise<Result> index() {
    final Promise<SomethingFromJson> eventualObject = WS.url("http://example.com/json")
                                                        .get()
                                                        .map(response -> // do something with the json);

    // add a callback to send mail when the json has been processed
    // this will happen in another thread
    eventualObject.onRedeem(new F.Callback<SomethingFromJson>() {
        // send email
    }, executionContext);

    return eventualObject.map(
        new Function<SomethingFromJson, Result>() {
            public Result apply(SomethingFromJson obj) {
                return ok(// whatever you do with obj);
        } 
      }
    );
}
```